# Using group/order by with union clause in sql query

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, amazon-redshift, union

I have four sql queries which gave me same columns so I am trying to combine them using `UNION` clause. Below is what I have tried but it gives me an error:

```
select clientid, 
'Test1' as client_name,
client_timestamp,
sum(client_counts) as count,
processIds as contracts
from output_1
group by 1,2,3,5
order by 1

UNION

select clientid, 
'Test2' as client_name,
client_timestamp,
sum(client_counts) as count,
'' as contracts
from output_2
group by 1,2,3,5
order by 1

UNION

select clientid, 
'Test3' as client_name,
client_timestamp,
sum(kite_count) as count,
process_metric as contracts
from output_3
group by 1,2,3,5
order by 1

UNION

select clientid, 
'Test4' as client_name,
execution_client_ts as client_timestamp,
sum(kite_count) as count,
process_data as contracts
from output_4
group by 1,2,3,5
order by 1
```

Error I get is "Invalid Syntax" around UNION line. Anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `union` query may only have one `order by` clause.

If you are satisfied with ordering the *whole resultset*, you can remove all `order by` clauses and just keep the very last one, at the end of the query. It applies to the entire dataset that `union` generates.

Note that your `UNION`s are equivalent to `UNION ALL`s - because the client name is different in each member - and should be phrased as such.

If, on the other hand, you want to order reach sub-result, then this is different. Basically you need a flag in each member, that can then be used to identify each group. The client name might be a good pick, so:

```
order by client_name, client_id
```

Comment: Do I need to surround all queries in bracket and then put order by at the end or just remove orderby from all except last and it should work? Below is fine?

`select .. from output1 group by 1,2,3,5 union all select .. from output2 group by 1,2,3,5 union all select .. from output1 group by 1,2,3,5 order by 1`

Comment: @AndyP: removing all except the last one should work, as showed in the documentation:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_example_union_query.html